# How to initialize a neural network by user defined parameters in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to implement a Neural Network using `tensorflow`. I want my model to initialize itself using default parameters or any weight size list passed by users. But the compute graph generated by my code seems incorrect. How can I initialize a NN by user-defined parameters in `tensorflow`?

```
def setUp(self):
    self.hidden_layer_ = len(self.hidden_layer_sizes)
    self.weights = []
    self.biases = []

    size_list = [self.input_size]
    size_list.extend(list(self.hidden_layer_sizes))
    i = 0

    while i + 1 < len(size_list):
        prev_size = size_list[i]
        size = size_list[i+1]
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([prev_size, size], stddev=0.1))
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size]))
        self.weights.append(w)
        self.biases.append(b)
        i += 1
    self.w_out = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([size_list[-1], self.output_size], stddev=0.1))
    self.b_out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([self.output_size]))

    self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.input_size], name='input')
    self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.output_size], name='label')
    self.keep_prob_plh = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)


    self.layers = [self.input_x]
    for w, b in zip(self.weights, self.biases):
        hidden = ACT_FUN_DICT[self.activation](tf.matmul(self.layers[-1], w) + b)
        hidden_drop = tf.nn.dropout(hidden, self.keep_prob_plh)
        self.layers.append(hidden_drop)

    with tf.variable_scope('output'):
        self.output_layer = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.layers[-1], self.w_out) + self.b_out)
    self.cost_func = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow((self.input_y - self.output_layer), 2)))
    self.cost_summary = tf.summary.scalar('Cost', self.cost_func)

    self.optimizer = SOLVER_DICT[self.solver](self.learning_rate).minimize(self.cost_func)

    root_logdir = './tf_logs'
    now = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    log_dir = "{}/run-{}/".format(root_logdir, now)
    self.file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir, tf.get_default_graph())

    self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

I implement the NN using a class, the size of weights are stored in the member `self.hidden_layer_sizes`.

```
class MLPClassifier(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), activation='relu', solver='sgd', alpha=0.0001,
             learning_rate=0.001, max_iter=200, random_state=42, keep_prob=0.75, logged = True):

        self.hidden_layer_sizes = hidden_layer_sizes
        self.activation = activation
        self.solver = solver
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.keep_prob = keep_prob
        self.fitted = False
        self.logged = True
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        self.sess.as_default()
```

That's all my code, and this is my [compute graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZFxT.png):

Comment: That "the compute graph seems incorrect" is too vague & broad statement

Comment: Your code already uses `self.hidden_layer_sizes` to construct the network, so please explain what it is that the code fail to do.

Comment: Oh, the parameter self.hidden_layer_sizes not construct the network, it just tell the   function the size of each layer I want, and the function will finish the job. My problem is the network structure doesn't like what I want, just like what you see in the image URL"compute graph" . It doesn't look like a NN, I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: I want to write a multi-layer perceptron, so the computer graph shouldn't look like that.